# C# Call shadow method with generic cast

Tags: c#, generics, shadow

I'm trying to write a method which casts an object to a generic type to execute a specific shadow method. This is my test code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        hello2 h2 = new hello2();
        test(h2);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void test(hello h)
    {
        h.write2<hello2>();
    }
}

class hello
{
    public virtual void write()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("hello");
    }

    public void write2<T>() where T : hello
    {
        T h2 = (T)this;
        hello2 h21 = (hello2)this;
        h2.write();
        h21.write();
    }
}

class hello2 : hello
{
    public new void write()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("hello2");
    }
}
```

My Console Output is:

hello

hello2

I debugged it, checked everything and couldn't find a mistake. The Output should be hello2 in both cases. Am I missing something obvious here? Or is this just not working?

Comment: use `override` instead of `new`.

Comment: @Selman22 That doesn't explain **why** it is not outputting 'hello2' at the moment.

Comment: This is just a sample. I cannot use override in my case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing you are missing is the method that is called is chosen at the compile time of `hello` not at the use of `write2`. So at compile time all the compiler knows is that `T` is of type `hello` or some other derived class so it chooses the shadowed method as that is the only method it knows about at compile time.

Think of it this way,  replace every `T` with whatever is on the right side of the `:`. This is what the compiler sees and uses that information to make its choices.

```
//What the complier sees when you compile even if you pass in hello2 as T.
public void write2<T>() where T : hello
{
    hello h2 = (hello)this;
    hello2 h21 = (hello2)this;
    h2.write();
    h21.write();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

When the method is declared as `virtual` the resolution of the method that will be called is deferred until runtime and depends on the type of the object at runtime. From the [C# spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645767(v=vs.71).aspx):

> In a virtual method invocation, the run-time type of the instance for
>   which that invocation takes place determines the actual method
>   implementation to invoke.

From the [C# spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645767(v=vs.71).aspx), the resolution of a virtual method is as follows:

> For every virtual method declared in or inherited by a class, there
>   exists a most derived implementation of the method with respect to
>   that class. The most derived implementation of a virtual method M with
>   respect to a class R is determined as follows:
>
> - If R contains the introducing virtual declaration of M, then this is    the most derived implementation of M.
> - Otherwise, if R contains **an override of M**, then this is the most derived implementation of M.
> - Otherwise, the most derived implementation of M with respect to R is    the same as the most derived implementation of M with respect to
>     the direct base class of R.

So when you write:

```
T h2 = (T)this;
h2.write();
```

The compiler knows h2 is of type `hello` or derived, and that `write` is a virtual method whose resolution will be deferred until runtime.

At runtime, the resolution will chose the method in class `hello` even though the class is of type `hello2`. This is because the `write` method in class `hello2` does not contains the `override` keyword and won't be considered when resolving the virtual call. (So the only way to call write on `hello2` is by making sure the compiler knows the instance is of type `hello2`)

This is also why if you declare write on `hello2` with **override** instead of **new** the output of the same program would be *hello2* in both cases.

**Edit**

It seems you want to write a method that is able to call `write` in `hello` or `hello2` even though the method has been declared with the new operator in `hello2`.

You could write a extension method that uses a `dynamic` variable. For example create the following extension method:

```
public static class HelloExtensions
{
    public static void writeDynamic<T>(this T h) where T: hello
    {
        dynamic hdynamic = h;
        hdynamic.write();
    }
}
```

Then you could write the following test program that uses that extension method with your original classes:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        testDynamic(new hello());
        testDynamic(new hello2());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void testDynamic(hello h)
    {
        h.writeDynamic();
    }
}
```

The output will be:

```
hello
hello2
```

Answer (score 0):

The `write` method that you are using in your method

```
public void write2<T>() where T : hello {
    T h2 = (T)this;
    hello2 h21 = (hello2)this;
    h2.write();  // <--- this one
    h21.write();
}
```

is the `write` method defined on the `hello` type (check it using intellisense). Therefore when you are actually calling the method with a specific T type of type `hello2` it is still the `write` method if type `hello`. And since you are defining the `write` method in type `hello2` using the new operator, this method is not called.

You can only use methods of type `hello2` if you explicitly cast it to type `hello2` *in your method*, and not to not-yet-known-type `T`.