# Cannot Call Overridden List<T>.Add(...) in C#

Tags: c#, .net, overriding, super, overloading

The following code gives the error
"Cannot convert type 'Calendar.Month' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'":

```
public class Month : List<Day>, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public Month() { /* NOP */ }

  public new void Add<Day>(Day pValue)
  {
    var list = (List<Day>)this;

    list.Add(pValue);
  }
}
```

I have studied the advice here:
[Why does calling a method in my derived class call the base class method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17717570/why-does-calling-a-method-in-my-derived-class-call-the-base-class-method)

and here:

[C# Call shadow method with generic cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25245322/c-sharp-call-shadow-method-with-generic-cast)

I want to override the List.Add(...) method with a Month.Add(...) method to send an event to the target XAML container classes and then call the overridden List.Add(...) method.

By the way, I am using VS2012, .NET 4.5, and the application is for Win Phone 8 (later versions are not presently an option - sorry).  I mention this because I know from experience a lot changed between Win Phone 8 and Win 10.

Comment: I'm sure you mean `base.Add(pValue);` instead of `list.Add(pValue);`

Comment: Instead of using inheritance why not use composition?

Comment: Why do you want to inherit from `List<T>` instead of `Collection<T>`?

Comment: Is a Month a List? Not so much. Siding with @juharr on this on. A month has a list of days.

Comment: I used List<T> instead of Collection<T> because that is how Laurent and Jaime did it in their 'Data Binding' lecture (minutes 40-49) found here:
https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/xaml-deep-dive-for-windows-windows-phone-apps-jump-start-8228?l=BIQ8v9Iy_204984382

Were they mistaken?  Are List<T> not usable when data binding the contents of an ItemsControl?   

PS. I am treating Month as a List<Day> for the purposes of this question.  It is intended to follow the approach taken by Laurent and Jaime.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is the use of the generic type parameter and all the casting around. Since you already derive your class from the generic `List<T>` to `List<Day>`, there is no need to have another type parameter.

Casting is not really useful here. Just use `base.`:

```
public new void Add(Day pValue)
{
    base.Add(pValue);
}
```

And instead of using a custom implementation of `List<T>`, use an `ObservableCollection<T>` which does all this for you already.

If you want to hold on to your list, implement `IList<T>` yourself and use a backing list to store the data. In that class you have total control over what you do when adding, deleting, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I have tried your suggestions and here is why I found:
1. implementing IList<T> myself works.  But the goal here is understanding so I also ..

Comment: _(the above comment is incomplete)_

Thank you for your comments.  I tried each of your suggestions out of curiosity and found:
**1.** implementing `IList<T>` compiles and items `Add(...)`.
**2.** using `List<T>` and calling using `base.Add(...)` works like above  - thanks I just forgot about 'base'.  This is what I needed.
**3.** `ObservableCollection<T>` compiles but I'm not familiar with it so having more of a struggle than I like replicating a simple behavior like `List<T>.Add(...)`.  I don't think it gets me much as I implemented `Month` class using `INotifyPropertyChanged` - right?

Comment: Yes, that should do @rfreytag